# android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl catch NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I need catch NullPointerException by FragmentManagerImpl.
But try ... catch does not work.
How to catch explicit NullPointerException on getItem()?

```
.......
        try {
              pagerAdapter = new TFragmentPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
        }

..................

 private class TFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public TFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (training) {
                case VAR:
//                    fragment = getTFragment(position);
                    fragment = null;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (fragment == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }

            return fragment;
        }
}
```

Stack trace I'm seeing

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field
>   'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object
>   reference
>           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:417)
>           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:412)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:99)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:869)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1019)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
>           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
>           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
>           at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:868)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
>           at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
>           at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: post the full logcat error/stacktrace

Comment: why is `fragment = getTFragment(position);` commented out ?   is that where you crash?

Comment: @petey one moment please

Comment: If I want something that matter, throw in this place and catch an error. Or, as is possible at this point to interrupt the code?

Comment: so, are you adding a null fragment in your viewpager?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted basically works.  Your problem lies elsewhere.  Edit your post and show us the code around ActivityThread.java:5257.

For your reference this code shows what you were trying to do in public Fragment getItem(int position)... throw the exception you want and that it can be caught.

```
package org.jf;

public class SomeClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SomeClass();
    }

    public SomeClass() {
        try {

            AClass x = new AClass();
            x.getItem(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Caught");
        }
    }

    class AClass {
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            int training = 1;
            Object fragment = null;
            switch (training) {
                case 1:
//                    fragment = getTFragment(position);
                    fragment = null;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (fragment == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }

            return fragment;
        }
    }
}
```